# Regarding present tense and future tense

Tags: tenses

In this sentence "Look at the timetable. Hurry up! Flight 4026 takes off at 6:20." Can I replace "will take off" with "takes off"？

Comment: Yes. Positively.

Comment: They do not mean the same. The Simple Present Tense (Present Indefinite) is used for something that happens regularly/ usually/ normally -- *Flight 4026* (generally) *takes off at 6:20* . On the other hand, the formal future tense *will*+verb indicates a (definite) possibility in the future.

Comment: @Kris Are you saying that it would be incorrect to say _The plane takes off at 6:20_ in the case where that route and timing had never been flown before and will never be flown again by that plane ?

Comment: @Frank [ell.se]

Comment: It could be a lot easier for you if you think of English tenses as a two-tense system (past and non-past), and *will* as just a modal verb (to express a possibility in the future). For what it's worth, I agree with njboot's answer below.

Comment: @Kris I got an answer from ELL and for the benefit of the OP it appears that _The plane takes off at 6:20_ is OK whether or not it's a regular/usual/normal thing. Here's is the [ELL question/answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23609/simple-present-formal-future-use-in-this-sentence)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Both sentences are grammatically correct.

> "Look at the timetable. Hurry up! Flight 4026 takes off at 6:20."
>
> "Look at the timetable. Hurry up! Flight 4026 will take off at 6:20."

A third (and equally viable alternative):

> "Look at the timetable. Hurry up! Flight 4026 is taking off at 6:20."

Pick whichever one sounds best, *to you*.