# SImple present to talk about the future

Tags: grammaticality, present-tense, future

Here is my question, are both of the following acceptable?

> I **start** dieting after Christmas.
>
> I **will start** dieting after Christmas.

This is the task from Oxford English Grammar Advanced.

Note: I know the answer, because I have the key, but in my opinion both sentences are grammatically correct, taking into account what we want to ephasize, so that's why I am asking.

EDIT: thank you Edwin Ashworth.
What about these sentences :

> Rob **comes** round after 7.
>
> Rob **is coming** round after 7.

Comment: Hello, linaaa. Does this answer your question? [Regarding present tense and future tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171032/regarding-present-tense-and-future-tense) Or this? [present simple in the future tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/519644/present-simple-in-the-future-tense) Perhaps best is [present tense for future events](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29141/present-tense-for-future-events).

Comment: To be fair, while both variants are grammatical, they wouldn't be used in exactly the same circumstances. The use of the present simple (I'd say in phase structure, inchoative 'start Ving') _I start dieting after Christmas_ is typically unmarked, a plain statement of intent, with no overtones (unless added by stress). Choosing _I will start dieting after Christmas_ would usually be used to show resignation or resolve; again, tone (wavery/detached, or determined) will differentiate in speech. //  'Rob comes round after 7' shows habitual practice, 'Rob is coming round after 7' is semelfactive.

Comment: See the completed comment; the answer given at the duplicate includes a sentence of this form (present comtinuous for future one-off event). How old is your book? Admittedly, 'He is coming round later' could well be seen as conversational/informal. But it's certainly idiomatic. See this good [BBC article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode73/languagepoint.shtml#:~:text=English%20speakers%20often%20use%20the,3%20o'clock%20tomorrow%20afternoon.).

Comment: Okey Edwin, thanks, but What if Rob doesn't always come round after 7- what if this is a plain statement of intent?

Comment: Then 'Rob comes round after 7', which is used almost exclusively to show habitual practice, is barred. It _could_ just be used if say you were going through a timetable of expected  visitors.

Comment: Thank you. What if i change the sentence to: Rob comes round tomorrow after 7. Here it doesn't sound like habitual action. Am i correct?

Comment: If you put in enough context to allow (or at least suggest) a future interpretation, you can do it with practically any construction, since there's no future tense. But if you use an active (not stative) predicate in the present without specifying a context, a generic is always an option.

Comment: Yes; 'Rob comes round tomorrow after 7' = 'Rob is due to come round tomorrow after 7'.